# Ionic 4 storage values going null on android device

Tags: android, cordova, local-storage, ionic4

I am using `cordova-sqlite-plugin` and `@ionic/storage` to locally store the data on the device. On the browser, I am easily getting stored values, but on the android device, all values are going null.
Here is my code :

```
    this.storage.get('name').then((val) =>{
      console.log("name is", val)
      this.name = val;
      console.log(this.name)


 this.storage.get('role').then((val) =>{
        console.log("role" , val)
        this.role = val;
        console.log(this.role)

      })
```

On the android device, both values are going null whereas working fine on the browser.
Thanks in advance

```
   this.storage.set('role',"Resellers")

 submit(email, name ){


    let mail = email
    let nm = name

    this.storage.set('name',nm)
}
```

Comment: did you set value in 'role' and 'name'? if yes please provide code.

Comment: Yes. I am also retriving it successfully  in browser

Comment: I have edited the question. the role is set with string and name is set with values passed with submit() function which is called on the button click

Comment: I am getting both values on browser but not on device

Comment: Do you have the same problems with Chrome on Android? Or do the values show?

Comment: Ye I am using chrome://inspect/*devices to view android device console. But with ionic serve it is working fine

Comment: Can you inspect and see which driver (of Ionic Storage) is used between browser and android?

Comment: You can use Localstorage instead of ionic Native storage , where localstorage is quite fast and reliable

Comment: Sorry for being late, but the problem is I am storing data on another page and getting on error. That is the reason I am getting null values on android. I think it is async await issue, but I can't find solution? Any idea anyone?